# ConcurrentModificationException when serializing a page in Wicket

Tags: wicket

In my application, a ConcurrentModificationException is sporadically thrown by Wicket when serializing a page. Unfortunately, I can't see what is causing it. Does anyone have an idea or how can I find the cause? I use Wicket 8.8.0. I don't use any maps in the MyPage page.

> JavaSerializer (Wicket-AsyncPageStore-PageSavingThread) > error writing object [Page class = MyPage, id = 38, render count = 1822]: null
> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
> at org.apache.commons.collections4.map.AbstractLinkedMap$LinkIterator.nextEntry(AbstractLinkedMap.java:574) ~[commons-collections4-4.4.jar:4.4]
> at org.apache.commons.collections4.map.AbstractLinkedMap$LinkMapIterator.next(AbstractLinkedMap.java:369) ~[commons-collections4-4.4.jar:4.4]
> at org.apache.commons.collections4.map.AbstractHashedMap.doWriteObject(AbstractHashedMap.java:1245) ~[commons-collections4-4.4.jar:4.4]
> at org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LinkedMap.writeObject(LinkedMap.java:134) ~[commons-collections4-4.4.jar:4.4]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1223.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1016) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1487) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1543) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1500) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:897) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1016) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1487) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1543) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1500) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:897) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1016) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1487) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1543) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1500) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1543) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1500) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:897) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1016) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1487) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1369) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1543) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1500) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1423) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1169) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$SerializationCheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:368) ~[wicket-core-8.8.0.jar:8.8.0]
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:341) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer.serialize(JavaSerializer.java:82) ~[wicket-core-8.8.0.jar:8.8.0]
> at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AbstractPageStore.serializePage(AbstractPageStore.java:133) ~[wicket-core-8.8.0.jar:8.8.0]
> at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.createSerializedPage(DefaultPageStore.java:281) ~[wicket-core-8.8.0.jar:8.8.0]
> at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.storePage(DefaultPageStore.java:61) ~[wicket-core-8.8.0.jar:8.8.0]
> at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousPageStore$PageSavingRunnable.run(AsynchronousPageStore.java:208) ~[wicket-core-8.8.0.jar:8.8.0]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly update to Wicket 8.14.0, there have been fixes for page serialization.